# How to use Spring OAuth2 Client authentication filter with custom web security configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have basic `Web` and `OAuth2 Client` Spring boot application. Just by adding following to `application.yml` Google SignIn works.

```yaml
spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
            client:
                registration:
                    google:
                        clientId: 1135813....
                        clientSecret: esdf...
```

But when a custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is added, OAuth2 authentication no longer works.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(User.withUsername("user").password("123").roles("USER"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests() //
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll() //
                .antMatchers("/login/social").permitAll() //
                .antMatchers("/login/social/google").permitAll() //
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

I want to keep basic authentication while OAuth2 authentication is working on the default redirect URL (`/login/oauth2/code/google`). How do I achieve this?

Comment: How did you access google resource in oauth2? Use OAuth2RestTemplate method?

Comment: @jacky-neo You literally don't need to do anything but add `Spring OAuth2 Client` and set client id and client secret. OAuth2 is pre-configured to support many social logins including Facebook, Google Github, etc..

Comment: at first I mean you can use OAuth2RestTemplate to invoke resource pretected by goole oauth2 and it will not be disturbed  by your custom security. now I understand what you want. You can use @EnableResourceServer to define which url be protected by google oauth2. after that, oauth2 authentication will be work.

Answer (score 0):

The below is demo about @EnableResourceServer

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;



@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final String[] urlPattern = {"/api/**"}; //eg.,  url protected by oauth2
        http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // or SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED for your required
            .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers(urlPattern)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(urlPattern)
            authenticated()
        ;

    }



}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question or address the problem.